# SQL Server: column to row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table (`table1`) with 2 columns `toypattern` and `additionalcolor`:

**Table 1**

```
toypattern  additionalcolor
FL38        orange
FL38        yellow
LF66        grey
LF66        black
```

and now I need to write a query to show the `toypattern` column, `1st color` column and `2nd color` column.  I need to display up to 5 additionalColor options

Desired output:

```
toypattern  1st color   2nd color     3rd color   4th color   5th color
  FL38        orange      yellow
  LF66        grey        black
```

How do I write such a SQL query?

Comment: Is there any other field that can be used to tell `1st` from `2nd` color?

Comment: hi peter,

there is no other field to tell 1st from 2nd color.Table 1 is the table that store all of the additionalcolor of a particular toypattern.

Comment: Is it arbitrary which is the "1st colour" and which is the 2nd? i.e it would be equally valid to have `(black),(grey)` as the last row? If not you need to store this information. You can't rely on some implicit ordering in the table.

Comment: Hi martin, it does not matter whihc colors comes first.as long as the additionalcolor is recorded in that particular toypattern. then in the desired output i need to show it. and the maximum additionalcolor for an toypattern is 4.

Comment: Are there always two additional colors? Or can that number vary per toypattern?

Comment: I edited the question to make the 5-color requirement clear.  There is no way I'm aware of to return a data with a variable number of columns from a single query.

Answer (score 2):

Try these:

```
;with cte as
(select toypattern, additionalcolor,
  row_number() over(partition by toypattern order by additionalcolor) As rn
from Table1)
select toypattern, 
  max(case when rn = 1 then additionalcolor end) as additionalcolor1,
  max(case when rn = 2 then additionalcolor end) as additionalcolor2
from cte
group by toypattern
```

This returns:

```
toypattern  additionalcolor1    additionalcolor2
FL38        Orange              Yellow
LF66        Black               Grey
```

downside of this is you need to add new MAX(...) lines for new additional colours.

////

Another solution would be to get the additional colours as CSV:

```
SELECT DISTINCT T1.toypattern,
STUFF((SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT ',' + s2.additionalcolor FROM Table1 AS s2 WHERE s2.toypattern = T1.toypattern ORDER BY ',' + s2.additionalcolor FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') AS Colours
FROM Table1 AS T1
ORDER BY T1.toypattern
```

This returns:

```
toypattern  Colours
FL38    Orange,Yellow
LF66    Black,Grey
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for the hint. i think i get the concept already.thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Ok. not sure if this question is related to this question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11070509/sql-query-issue-on-left-join):

But here's a solution that might be what you're after - took some of 03Usr's code (the row_number in particular and added pivoting):

```
;with cte as
(select toypattern, additionalcolor,
  rowno =  row_number() over(partition by toypattern order by additionalcolor)
from Table1)
SELECT
  ToyPattern
  --, ToyName
  , 'color 1' = [1]
  , 'color 2' = [2]
  , 'color 3' = [3]
  , 'color 4' = [4]
  , 'color 5' = [5]
FROM (  
  SELECT
  ToyPattern
  --, ToyName
  , rowno
  , additionalcolor
  FROM
    cte
) AS tac PIVOT (
  MAX (additionalcolor) FOR rowno in ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5])
) AS PivotTable
```

Comment: I am in love with this solution.  I don't understand it at all, which is the best possible state for me to find myself when looking at a piece of SQL.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
   first.toypattern,
   first.additionalColor,
   second.additionalColor
FROM
   Table1 first
   INNER JOIN Table2 second ON first.toypattern = second.toypattern
WHERE
   first.additionalColor < second.additionalColor
```

Problem being, you'll get back several matches if there are more than two colors per pattern.

edit: This doesn't really get back the results one might wish for when searching for more than 2 colors.  However, given the comments attached to this answer I won't delete it.

Comment: hmmm,this query works only for 2 additonalcolor right? lets say if i were to record more colors and some toy pattern might have color 3 or color 4, and those without color 3 and color 4 i would want to put a NULL for it. how would i code this in?

Comment: @chewhengchong: This is an important information that you should edit into your original question.

Comment: hi peter, yes the original question is that this query need to be able to query a toypattern that have a maximum of 5 additonalcolor per toy pattern.

Answer (score 0):

What Sql Server version do you use? (I can't add comments) A Pivot like the one posted above would be the best, but in case you're using and old Sql Server version (like 2000) you could do this using a CURSOR:

```
drop table #temp
create table #temp
(
   toypattern varchar(20),
   additionalcolor1 varchar(20),
   additionalcolor2 varchar(20),
   additionalcolor3 varchar(20),
   additionalcolor4 varchar(20),
   additionalcolor5 varchar(20)
)

declare @toypattern as varchar(20)
declare @additionalcolor as varchar(20)     
declare @Counter integer 
declare @StrSql varchar(200)    
declare @LastToyPattern as varchar(20)

set @LastToyPattern = ''

declare MyCursor cursor for  select toypattern, additionalcolor from table1 order by toypattern
open MyCursor
fetch next from MyCursor into @toypattern, @additionalcolor 

   while @@fetch_status = 0     
   begin
      if (@LastToyPattern <> @toypattern)
      begin
         if (@LastToyPattern <> '') 
         begin
            set @StrSql = @StrSql + replicate(',null', 5 - @Counter)    
            exec(@StrSql)
         end
         set @Counter = 0
         set @StrSql = 'insert into #temp select ''' + @toypattern + ''''
      end
      set @StrSql = @StrSql + ', ''' + @additionalcolor + ''''  
      set @Counter = @Counter + 1
      set @LastToyPattern = @toypattern
      fetch next from MyCursor into @toypattern, @additionalcolor
   end
set @StrSql = @StrSql + replicate(',null', 5 - @Counter)
exec(@StrSql)
close MyCursor
deallocate MyCursor
select * from #temp
```