# SQL query issue on left join

Tags: sql-server, join

I have two tables and I need to show the `additionalcolors` for toys that have only 1 toypattern. Example (FW18,FK97,FK38,LX74). I have used a left outer join from `Toytypes` to `Toyadditionalcolor` and also performed a subquery to find the toypattern that only have a toyname. But I am still not able to get the results like the result query below.

Please tell me which part of my code I need to modify in order to get similar results to the query1 table below?

**ToyTypes**

```
ToyPattern   ToyName           mainColor
----------   ---------------   ---------
  F692         Dino             pink       
  F692         Elephant         pink         
  FK38         Elephant         pink         
  FK97         Giraffe          purple     
  FW18         Sonic            pink       
  LX73         Kangaroo         pink       
  LX73         Cow              blush       
  LX73         Dog              pink       
  LX74         Cat              plum
```

**ToyAdditionalColor**

```
 ToyPattern  ToyName     firstColor    additionalColor
 ----------  ----------  -----------   ----------------
    FK38     Elephant    pink          orange
    FK38     Elephant    pink          yellow
    LX74     cat         plum          dark pink
    LX74     cat         plum          pale pink
```

Desired output:

```
ToyPattern  ToyName     color 1      color 2      color 3      color 4      color 5      
----------- ----------  ------------ ------------ ------------ ------------ ------------
FK38        Elephant    pink         orange       yellow       NULL         NULL    
FK97        Giraffe     purple       NULL         NULL         NULL         NULL
FW18        Sonic       pink         NULL         NULL         NULL         NULL
LX74        cat         plum         dark pink    pale pink    NULL         NULL
```

Below here is my SQL code.

```
select distinct 
    toytypes.toypattern,
    toyname,
    toytypes.flowerBreed,
    toytypes.firstColor as 'color 1'
from 
    Toytypes 
left join 
    ToyAdditionalColor on ToyAdditionalColor.toypattern = Toytypes.toypattern
where 
    toytypes.toypattern in 
              (select Toypattern
               from Toytypes 
               group by toypattern
               having count(toypattern) < 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

hmmm I'd prefer to start by normalising `ToyAdditionalColor`  to become something like: ToyPattern, ToyName, Color, SortOrder.

Example data would be: 'FK38', 'Elephant', 'pink', 1.

Second row: 'FK38', 'Elephant', 'orange', 2.

After that, you can use `PIVOT` - I haven't got Management Studio with me at the moment, but I think it might look like this:

```
SELECT
  ToyPattern
  , ToyName
  , 'color 1' = 1
  , 'color 2' = 2
  , 'color 3' = 3
  , 'color 4' = 4
  , 'color 5' = 5
FROM (  
  SELECT
  ToyPattern
  , ToyName
  , SortOrder
  , Color
  FROM
    dbo.ToyAdditionalColor
) AS ToyAdditionalColor PIVOT (
  MAX (Color) FOR SortOrder IN (1,2,3,4,5)
) AS PivotTable
```

Comment: Hi YS,the problem now is we're not suppose to perform normalize.and yes, the tables are not normalized.and we're required to  perform the query using the above table and get the result same as the desired output.

Comment: thanks for the hint. i think i get the concept already.thanks!