# Transpose Column Value to Row in T-SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql

I know this might have been asked before but I really could not find the answer. I have a temporary table named `#TEMP` which looks like this:

```
+===============================+=============================+
| NAME                          | ATTRIBUTE                   |
+===============================+=============================+                                  
| BadgeType                     | Permanent                   |
+-------------------------------+-----------------------------+
| PrimaryLocationInCompany      | No                          |
+-------------------------------+-----------------------------+
| AdminAccessToProductionServer | No                          |
+-------------------------------+-----------------------------+
| AccessToImportantFIles        | No                          |
+-------------------------------+-----------------------------+
| Waiver_Number                 | 56987                       |
+-------------------------------+-----------------------------+
| Summary                       | User not much active        |
+-------------------------------+-----------------------------+
| TimeStamp                     | 3/3/2009                    |
+-------------------------------+-----------------------------+
| UserID                        | 86478925                    |
+-------------------------------+-----------------------------+
```

What I want to do is to transpose both the `Name` and `Attribute` values to rows. The `Attribute` values may vary but the `Name` values are always fixed.

The result should look like this:

```
+----------+---------------+------------------------------+--------------------------------+-----------------------+--------------------------------------------------------+----------+-----------+
| UserID   | BadgeType     | PrimaryLocationIntelFacility | adminAccessToProductionServer  | AccessToClassifiedData| Info_Sec_Waiver_Number                                 | Summary  | TimeStamp |
+----------+---------------+------------------------------+--------------------------------+-----------------------+--------------------------------------------------------+----------+-----------+
| 11313403 | GREEN         | No                           | No                             | No                    | This contingent worker is eligible for remote access.  | 3/3/2009 |           |
+----------+---------------+------------------------------+--------------------------------+-----------------------+--------------------------------------------------------+----------+-----------+
```

Comment: do you have a common identifier for all that rows?

Comment: Your result table is messed up. You have not the same numbers of columns in the two rows. Furthermore, i.e., where does the `PrimaryLocationIntelFacility` comes from ?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/13454984/62576

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT UserID,BadgeType,PrimaryLocationInCompany,AdminAccessToProductionServer,AccessToImportantFIles,WaiverNumber,Summary,[TimeStamp]
FROM
(
    SELECT * FROM #Temp
) p
PIVOT
(
    MIN([ATTRIBUTE]) FOR [NAME] IN(BadgeType,PrimaryLocationInCompany,AdminAccessToProductionServer,AccessToImportantFIles,WaiverNumber,Summary,[TimeStamp],UserID)
) T
```

Also check the below for dynamic columns

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + [NAME]
                    from #Temp
                    group by [NAME]
            FOR XML PATH('')) 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT  ' + @cols + ' from 
             (
                select * from #Temp
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                MAX([ATTRIBUTE])
                for [NAME] in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute(@query)
```